# scipy - why isn't COBYLA respecting constraint?

Tags: scipy, lexical-scope

I'm using COBYLA to do a cost minimization on a linear objective function with constraints. I'm implementing lower and upper bounds by including a constraint for each.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

def linear_cost(factor_prices):
    def cost_fn(x):
        return np.dot(factor_prices, x)
    return cost_fn


def cobb_douglas(factor_elasticities):
    def tech_fn(x):
        return np.product(np.power(x, factor_elasticities), axis=1)
    return tech_fn

def mincost(targets, cost_fn, tech_fn, bounds):

    n = len(bounds)
    m = len(targets)

    x0 = np.ones(n)  # Do not use np.zeros.

    cons = []

    for factor in range(n):
        lower, upper = bounds[factor]
        l = {'type': 'ineq',
             'fun': lambda x: x[factor] - lower}
        u = {'type': 'ineq',
             'fun': lambda x: upper - x[factor]}
        cons.append(l)
        cons.append(u)

    for output in range(m):
        t = {'type': 'ineq',
             'fun': lambda x: tech_fn(x)[output] - targets[output]}
        cons.append(t)

    res = scipy.optimize.minimize(cost_fn, x0,
                                  constraints=cons,
                                  method='COBYLA')

    return res
```

COBYLA doesn't respect the upper or lower-bound constraints, but it does respect the technology constraint.

```
>>> p = np.array([5., 20.])
>>> cost_fn = linear_cost(p)

>>> fe = np.array([[0.5, 0.5]])
>>> tech_fn = cobb_douglas(fe)

>>> bounds = [[0.0, 15.0], [0.0, float('inf')]]

>>> mincost(np.array([12.0]), cost_fn, tech_fn, bounds)
       x: array([ 24.00010147,   5.99997463])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
   maxcv: 1.9607782064667845e-10
    nfev: 75
  status: 1
 success: True
     fun: 239.99999999822359
```

Why wouldn't COBYLA respect the first factor constraint (i.e. upper-bound @ 15)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

COBYLA *is* in fact respecting all the bounds you give.

The problem lies in the construction of the `cons` list.
Namely, binding of variables in lambda and other inner-scoped functions in Python (and Javascript) is lexical, and does not behave in the way you assume: http://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/ After the loop is finished, the variables `lower` and `upper` have values `0` and `inf`, and variable `factor` has value `1`, and these values are what is then used by all of the lambda functions.

One workaround is to explicitly bind the specific values of variables to dummy keyword arguments:

```
for factor in range(n):
    lower, upper = bounds[factor]
    l = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, a=lower, i=factor: x[i] - a}
    u = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, b=upper, i=factor: b - x[i]}
    cons.append(l)
    cons.append(u)

for output in range(m):
    t = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, i=output: tech_fn(x)[i] - targets[i]}
    cons.append(t)
```

A second way is to add a factory function generating the lambdas.

Comment: Wow. That's the first time Python's scoping caught me.